# Explanation For Factory Method

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm learning the factory method,when and why to use,but one thing that was a little bit ambiguous is that why are we using the static keyword for the factory method,can somebody clarify.
as shown in the code below:

```
enum VehicleType { 
    VT_TwoWheeler,    VT_ThreeWheeler,    VT_FourWheeler 
}; 

// Library classes 
class Vehicle { 
public: 
    virtual void printVehicle() = 0; 
    static Vehicle* Create(VehicleType type); 
}; 
class TwoWheeler : public Vehicle { 
public: 
    void printVehicle() { 
        cout << "I am two wheeler" << endl; 
    } 
}; 
class ThreeWheeler : public Vehicle { 
public: 
    void printVehicle() { 
        cout << "I am three wheeler" << endl; 
    } 
}; 
class FourWheeler : public Vehicle { 
    public: 
    void printVehicle() { 
        cout << "I am four wheeler" << endl; 
    } 
}; 

// Factory method to create objects of different types. 
// Change is required only in this function to create a new object type 
Vehicle* Vehicle::Create(VehicleType type) { 
    if (type == VT_TwoWheeler) 
        return new TwoWheeler(); 
    else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler) 
        return new ThreeWheeler(); 
    else if (type == VT_FourWheeler) 
        return new FourWheeler(); 
    else return NULL; 
}
```

PS: This code can be found on GeeksForGeeks.

Comment: @TedLyngmo
the code didn't even compile without the static keyword,what's the purpose of it,that's my question

Comment: You must have a very specific purpose? If it is "I want to learn EVERYTHING in this code" you are grasping for too much. Pick a piece and ask - how does this work? Don't dump everything you don't understand.

Comment: @TedLyngmo
there is no problem i'm trying to solve,i'm just trying to understand the concept behind factory method,understood what it does and all,but why should we use the static keyword,how it affects the code

Comment: I won't answer that last comment since it'll be just a repetition.

Comment: totally got the point ty

Answer (score 1):

Static method is one method for the type of the class. That means you don't need a variable for the class `Vehicle` if you call `Create` method. You call this method like that: `Vehicle::Create(YOU_TYPE)` and not like 'regular' method with a class variable. Also `Vehicle` have a pure virtual method, that's why you can't have a variable of this class and there so the method is static.

Comment: Appreciate your help,now i know what exactly static means in this code.so Abstract classes can’t be instantiated,and so we can’t create an object so instead i can’t use any member function of the abstract class,unless it’s static so we can make it like global function or smth like that?

Comment: Yes, you can use global function for this method.